# Android TextView Set and Get TypeFace

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview, typeface

I need to store bold, italic and font family of textView and retrieve the same from DB :

So, I get the TypeFace from the TextView and
Later I am trying to set it back. But I am getting a crash without even displaying any error.

Whats the correct way to do this ?

```
Gson GsonPkjVar = new Gson();
JsonObject textViewJsnVar = new JsonObject();
```

|*| Converting Typeface to Gson String and Storing in JsonObject :

```
textViewJsnVar.addProperty("TxtFntKey", GsonPkjVar.toJson(textViewVar.getTypeface()));
```

|*| Converting Gson String back to Typeface from JsonObject :

```
textViewVar.setTypeface(GsonPkjVar.fromJson(textViewJsnVar.get("TxtFntKey").getAsString(), Typeface.class));
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: Why dont you save name of font and then load on runtime,

Comment: How do I get tha name of name of font  dynamically ?  like .getTypeface().getFontFamily()

Answer (score 0):

Use type token instead

```
Type type=new TypeToken<Typeface>(){}.getType();
Typeface typeface=GsonPkjVar.fromJson(textViewJsnVar.get("TxtFntKey").getAsString(),type);
```

Comment: This dint help me. Getting same crash. Can you explain what is the difference between my method and TypeToken Method ?

Comment: post the crash also.Type is to specify the type you want to deserialize the data.

Comment: As I hav mentioned in my question its crashing without even displaying any error